# List of all extras applicable to an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to know what all extra-keys are applicable to a particular intent? For example if i create an intent,

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

then the following putExtra calls are some that are applicable.

```
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
```

So how can I get the list of all the extra-keys that are related to the intent?

Comment: Look here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968896/listing-all-extras-of-an-intent

Do a search before posting a question.

Comment: @Hades - That question considers the inverse problem: given an intent, what extras are in it? OP is asking about how to know what extras are meaningful to put into an intent in the first place.

Comment: @Hades No that's not what I want. That code lists the extras I have already put into the intent. What i want is a method to list all the possible keys that I can put into the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the only way to know what extras are supported is to look at the documentation for the action. If the source code is available, that's the only other way to know.

In your particular example, unofficial documentation can be found [here](http://www.mvwsolutions.com/crop_large_photos_with_android). The source code happens to be available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/3574026/src/com/android/camera/crop). Look in [CropExtras.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/3574026/src/com/android/camera/crop/CropExtras.java) for the available keys and dig through [CropActivity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/3574026/src/com/android/camera/crop/CropActivity.java) for how they are used. However, note that using `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is probably not a good idea, as explained [in this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) and in the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758425/how-to-set-the-output-image-use-com-android-camera-action-crop).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That blog post was helpful as well. Now I know why the android developer documentation doesn't have any info regarding those constants.

Comment: @TedHopp, nice and informative answer as usual. Keep the good work up.+1 definitely.